# Select the rows with top values until the sum value reach the 30% of total value in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Python pandas and have a data frame that is pulled from my CSV file:

```
ID          Value
123         10
432         14
213         12
'''
214         2
999         43
```

I was advised using the following code can randomly select some rows with the condition that the sum of the selected values = 30% of the total value. ("close to 30%" works)

```
out = df.sample(frac=1).loc[lambda d: d['Value'].cumsum().le(d['Value'].sum()*0.3)]
```

Now I want to sort the rows based on the value and select the top rolls until they add up to 30% of the total value.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then find the mask that are `True` and select rows from `df_sorted` with [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values('Value').reset_index(drop=True)
m = df_sorted['Value'].cumsum().le(df['Value'].sum()*0.3)
print(df_sorted.loc[m])
```

Output:

```
    ID  Value
0  214      2
1  123     10
2  213     12
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
df.iloc[
    df['Value']
    .sort_values()
    .cumsum()[lambda x: x <= 0.3 * df['Value'].sum()]
    .index]
```

Output:

```
    ID  Value
3  214      2
0  123     10
2  213     12
```